# Custom Angular modal service does not work correctly, component does not receive updates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating a service in Angular to open the components inside my modal, but I noticed something... for some reason, after I inject the content of my component inside the modal and insert it into the html of my page, things inside my component do not work as they should.

For example, when I am normally on my route to the component that I want to open via modal, it works correctly, I enter the data in the form, it checks whether it is valid or invalid and releases the save button... But, when this same component is opened by my modal service, it simply remains immutable, even after completing all the fields, it still remains invalid, it's as if it didn't change anything, remaining in an immutable state.

My code:

```
import { Injectable, Injector, ComponentFactoryResolver, Type, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { ModalComponent } from "../components/modal/modal.component";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

    private modalNotifier!: Subject<void>;

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
    
    open(component: Type<any>, options: { title?: string, width?: string, height?: string }): Observable<any> {

        // Cria o componente de modal.
        const modalComponentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);
        const modalDynamicComponent = modalComponentFactory.create(this.injector);
        
        // Configura as variáveis internas do modal.
        modalDynamicComponent.instance.closeEvent.subscribe(() => this.close());
        modalDynamicComponent.instance.title = options?.title;
        modalDynamicComponent.instance.width = options?.width;
        modalDynamicComponent.instance.height = options?.height;

        // Detecta as mudanças nas váriaveis do instance.
        modalDynamicComponent.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

        // Cria o component especifico.
        const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);

        componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

        // Adiciona o conteudo do componente criado no modal.
        modalDynamicComponent.instance.contentViewRef.insert(componentRef.hostView);

        // Adiciona na página o modal.
        this.document.body.appendChild(modalDynamicComponent.location.nativeElement);

        this.modalNotifier = new Subject();
        return this.modalNotifier.asObservable();

    }

    close() {
        this.modalNotifier.next();
        this.modalNotifier.complete();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to attach your container component to the app like this:
Fristly inject `appRef`

```
appRef = inject(ApplicationRef);
```

After your component is created do:

```
this.appRef.attachView(yourComponent.hostView);
```

Additionaly you don't need to use `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

use `createComponent()` function from `@angular/core` instead

Comment: I tried to look for some way to insert another component into the newly created one... is there such a possibility? For example, I created the component as you said and it worked, however, I wanted to add another component created by createComponent within the ModalComponent... I hope you understand.

Comment: @RenanGS it is possible. Your componenet should have `ViewContainerRef` of itself.
You can do it by using a directive and a shared service.
Then later after creation of the component you write `parentComponent.instance.viewContainerRef.insert(childComponent.hostView)` and attach it to the app.